# Intensity Transformation using Fuzzy sets

Tags: image-processing

I'm doing a project on intensity transformation using fuzzy sets. In the book Digital Image Processing by Rafael C. Gonzalez. The author says this

> Consider the general problem of contrast enhancement, one of the
>   principal applications of intensity transformations.We can state the
>   process of enhancing the contrast of a gray-scale image using the
>   following rules:
>
> - IF a pixel is dark, THEN make it darker.
> - IF a pixel is gray, THEN make it gray.
> - IF a pixel is bright, THEN make it brighter.

and equation

$$v_0 = \frac{\mu_\text{dark}(z0) \times v_d + \mu_\text{gray} (z0) \times v_g + \mu_\text{bright} (z0) \times v_b}{
\mu_\text{dark}(z0) + \mu_\text{gray} (z0)  + \mu_\text{bright} (z0)}\tag{3.8-22}
$$

but how do we calculate the $ \mu_\text{dark}$, $\mu_\text{gray}$ and $\mu_\text{bright}$ values?

these are supposed to be the membership functions and how do we deduce the membership function values and calculate the new pixel values?

> [image: p.187]
>   [image: p.188]

Comment: Do you use MATLAB? Have you tried Fuzzy Logic Toolbox? I suggest you to watch parts of [this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O348HnWPm7A) which was shared by MATLAB on its own youtube channel. Membership function in your question is chosen as triangular function scaled between 0 and 255 as pixel values. According to membership function you will automatically have $\mu_\text{dark}$, $\mu_\text{gray}$ and $\mu_\text{bright}$ when you input a pixel value $z_0$.

Comment: I'm trying to code it in java.